# how to set ul/li bullet point color?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change bullets color in a list without span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470214/change-bullets-color-in-a-list-without-span)

Normally, the bullet point in ul/li is a black solid circle. I want to change the style of it, like I want to set the color of the bullet point to be green, I also want to change the bullet point to be a square. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 55):

Apply the color to the `li` and set the `span` (or other child element) color to whatever color the text should be.

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: square;
}

ul > li
{
    color: green;
}

ul > li > span
{
    color: black;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evanmulawski/YTRQ5/)

Comment: Doesn't work. The bullet and the text becomes green this way.

Comment: @timing: I clarified the answer and added a JSFiddle.

Comment: ul  > li {  color: red; }  works perfect

Answer (score 13):

A couple ways this can be done:

This will make it a square

```
ul
{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

This will make it green

```
li
{
  color: #0F0;
}
```

This will prevent the text from being green

```
li p
{
  color: #000;
}
```

However that will require that all text within lists be in paragraphs so that the color is not overridden.

A better way is to make an image of a green square and use:

```
ul
{
  list-style: url(green-square.png);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

You need to use `list-style-type:` to change bullet type/style and the above link has all of the options listed. As others have stated the color is changed using the `color` property on the `ul` itself

To create 'black filled' bullets, use 'disc' instead of 'circle',i.e.:

> list-style-type:disc

Comment: w3schools is ok, at least Paul Irish thinks so, now!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is controlled by the css `color` property applied to the element.