# How do i change color of a bullet without using span?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change bullets color in a list without span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470214/change-bullets-color-in-a-list-without-span)

Is it possible to change the bullet color in a list without using span class and image ?

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>java</li>
    <li>oracle</li>
    <li>php</li>
    <li>mysql</li>
</ul>
```

Note: I don't want to use `<span>` in between `<li>`.

Comment: You can use the list-style-image [list-style-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp) property

Answer (score 1):

```
li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge it is the method to color the bullets without using span.

css:

```
li {
          list-style: none;
        }

        li:before {
          /* For a round bullet */
          content:'\2022';
          /* For a square bullet */
          /*content:'\25A0';*/
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          max-width: 0px;
          max-height: 0px;
          left: -10px;
          top: -0px;
          color: red;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
```

html:

```
<ul>
        <li>java</li>
        <li>oracle</li>
        <li>php</li>
        <li>mysql</li>
      </ul>
```