# Add left border to list items, outside of bullet number

Tags: html, css

I have an OL list of numbered LI items. I want to put a left border around each separate LI element. However, I am only able to put the border to the right of the bullet number, and I want it to the left.

Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/

I want to keep the div wrapper around the LI elements.

```
<ol>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div> 
</ol>
```

Styles:

```
.li_wrapper{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

li{
    border-left:red 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: FYI a `div` in an `ol` is not valid html, only `li` is permitted

Comment: the red lines are to the left of the numbers in your fiddle ? do you mean to the right

Comment: just put `list-style: inside;` on the li css

Comment: In this thread it explains what can you do and how to target the bullets in OL and UL lists
[Link to UL OL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470214/change-bullets-color-in-a-list-without-span)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/z7gkLnc7/2/)

[`list-style-position: inside;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)

> The list-style-position CSS property specifies the position of the
>   marker box in the principal block box.

Comment: So what's the difference between this and your original fiddle ? They are showing up exactly the same on my Computer, That's why I though you had got confused with the left and right.....

Answer (score 0):

Hay you can do it like this :
Just change the `padding-left`, if you like the red line be more left.

```
.li_wrapper{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

li{
    border-left:red 2px solid;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px

}
```

Comment: This removes the bullet, but I need the steps to be numbered. I made a jsfiddle of your solution, with bullets:  http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/1/  The red line is still not outside the bullet number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `list-style` to decimal as well. Then it's exactly what you need.

```
li  {
  border-left:red 2px solid;
  list-style: decimal inside;     /*append this line*/
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyg3wav1)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by removing the normal numbers and add a pseudo class.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none; /* No default numbers */
    *list-style: decimal; /* Fallback for IE6/7 */
}
```

Then add a number before you your element in your `li` (for example wrap it in a `span`:

```
.li span:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    /* Add your styles like border-left */
}
```

[Roger Johansson wrote about that](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/) for further information!

Answer (score 0):

add content , like this

```css
#one li::before{content:" ";border-left:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<ol id="one">

        <li> I am a line</li>
    
        <li> I am a line</li>
    
</ol>
```