# How to change the color of dots in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have image with dots captions (toltips) and i can't change color this bullets to red. How i do that?
http://all4holidays.pl/kropki/

Comment: Post your code. This is using `canvas` so there will be a js file where the color of the element created on click is defined. You will be able to change the color there.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GmjxfQXz

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question itself. We're not going to visit external sites. Also see [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470214/change-bullets-color-of-an-html-list-without-using-span

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {list-style: none;}
li::before {
  content: "• ";
  color: red;
  font-size:20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ul>
```