# How to add background color to a text?

Tags: html, css

Is there a better way to write this code without using the *span* tag I want to add background color to my text

**Code**:

```css
.subject {
  color: gold;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Subjects</h2>
<ol>
  <li><span class="subject"> Physics</span> </li>

  <br>
  <li><span class="subject"> Astronomy</span></li>

  <br>
  <li><span class="subject">Mathematics<span></li>
            </ol>
```

I have used an external link for CSS

Comment: `li{background:gray;}`?

Comment: instead of "background" use : "background-color"

Comment: I tried that but doesn't do anything. i want to add background color to the text without the span txt.

Comment: See the comment on the question that someone linked as a duplicate, you can _approximate_ the effect using `::first-line` — as long as your `li`s don't span multiple lines this would work. I would add an answer if you can get others to vote to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `width: max-content;` on `li` to wrap `background` around text only

Use `li` to set initial color of numbers to black (or something else)  only and then use `li::first-line` to set your deserted effect on text.

Read about it more here:
[Change bullets color of an HTML list without using span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470214/change-bullets-color-of-an-html-list-without-using-span)

```css
li  {
color: black
}


li::first-line {
  color: gold;
  background-color: gray;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Subjects</h2>
<ol>
  <li><span class="subject"> Physics</span> </li>

  <br>
  <li><span class="subject"> Astronomy</span></li>

  <br>
  <li><span class="subject">Mathematics</span></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't affect *just* the `:text` without using a `<span>` or some other way to mark the text you want to style, but you can *approximate* it by using the `::first-line` pseudo-selector. This would work for cases where your list items don't span multiple lines.

You also don't need to put a class on every list item; you can put a class on the list itself and use that to target the styling. I added `class="subjects"` to the  `<ol>` for that.

I also removed the `<br>` line breaks; you can and should use `margin` to create space in-between elements. This is done with the `.subjects li` rule.

The main rule to get the gold-on-gray style you want is by targeting the "first-line" in all list items within a `.subjects` ordered (or unordered) list, using the selector `.subjects li::first-line`

```css
.subjects li {
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}
.subjects li::first-line {
  color: gold;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Subjects</h2>
<ol class="subjects">
  <li>Physics</li>
  <li>Astronomy</li>
  <li>Mathematics</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it on the `li`

```css
li {
  color: gold;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Subjects</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Physics</li>

  <br>
  <li>Astronomy</li>

  <br>
  <li>Mathematics</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but it _**is**_ different — the numbering becomes gold (instead of black) and the background extends to the whole width of the `li`